# splitting values column cells in R

Tags: r, split, coordinates

I have a DataFrame called SF_Fire with a column "Location" that contains both the longitude and latitude of a location. See code below:

> SF_fire$Location[1]
>   [1] (37.78515100003, -122.426449)

When I call the value of the column, it returns that the output is an integer.

> typeof(SF_fire$Location[1])
>   [1] "integer"

I want to split each of these cells values into a column with the longitude and a column with the latitude values so I can use these coordinates for my map.

Does anyone know how this could be resolved?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the output of this `dput(SF_fire[1,"Location"])`?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_extract_all`

```
library(stringr)
do.call(rbind, str_extract_all(SF_fire$Location, "-?[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is entry in Location a string delimited by a comma? E.g. "(37.78515100003, -122.426449)"

If so, you could first remove the parentheses, split each row by comma, convert to a numeric, make into a dataframe, and assign column names:

```
df <- gsub('[\\(\\)]', '', SF$Location)
df <- strsplit(df, ',')
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(df, as.numeric))
colnames(df) <- c('Lat', 'Long')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use library(splitstackshape). I have found it very helpful for cleaning data.

```
eg: SF_Fire_new<-cSplit(SF_Fire,"Location",",",drop=FALSE)
```